# Ensure newly created files/folders are owned by parent folder's user AND group

Tags: debian, users

Looking at other questions, I've done the following:

```
chmod g+s MEDIA 
setfacl -R -d -m g::rwx MEDIA 
setfacl -R -d -m o::rwx MEDIA
```

NOTE: MEDIA is a folder I'm looking to set up so that all files/folders added have the same user/group as the parent folder.

In this example MEDIA is owned by the user `Bob` and group `SharedFiles`.  The goal is for newly created files/folders to retain this ownership (both `Bob` and `SharedFiles`:

```
MEDIA Bob SharedFiles
MEDIA/NewFolder Bob Bob   <BAD
MEDIA/NewFolder Bob SharedFiles   <GOOD
```

If I create a subfolder whilst logged in as user 'Bob' that folder is owned by Bob:SharedFiles with [rwxrwxrwx] permissions (as intended). All Good!

If I login as Sue, the new folder becomes part of Sue:Sue with [rwxr-xr-x].

If I login from a different machine via a mounted drive in KDE (user Sue) the folder becomes part of Bob:Bob with [rwxr-xr-x].

Now both Bob and Sue are part of SharedFiles, where am I going wrong.  I want all users in SharedFiles group to have RWX permissions and I want all files/folders created by users in SharedFiles group to have the same user/group as the parent folder, why does this only happen with the owner on the machine itself.

```
getfacl MEDIA/
```

returns

```
# file: MEDIA/
# owner: Bob
# group: SharedFiles
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

samba.conf contains:

```
[MEDIA]
 read only = no
 locking = yes
 path = /mnt/local/int001/MEDIA
 guest ok = yes
 create mask = 0775
 directory mask = 0775
```

Comment: Your statement "_If I login from a different machine via a mounted drive in KDE (UserB) [...]_" doesn't make sense. Do you mean you mount the `MEDIA` folder from a remote machine? If so, which network filesystem protocol are you using to do so?

Comment: Yes, mounting the MEDIA folder remotely, using CIFS, providing Bob and his password when requested by the file browser

Comment: So... you need to look at your Samba configuration for that share.

Comment: On Linux, a newly created file's owner is set to the `uid` of the creating process, and the file's owner cannot be changed by a non-superuser user, even if the user is the owner of the file. This means you can't give away your files. If there was a mechanism (say by setting the user suid bit on a directory), then this rule could be circumvented by two co-operating regular users. Thus you can't set up a directory so that a file created by a local user would end up being inherited from the directory.

Comment: @roaima create and directory mask are both set to 0775 in samba.conf

Comment: @JohanMyréen But when I create a folder whilst logged in as SameMachine/'Bob', the folder becomes owned by 'Bob:SharedFiles', so why not when I'm logged in as DifferentMachine/'Bob'?

Comment: @JohanMyréen that doesn't necessarily follow for files created through a Samba share

Comment: Apologies, i tend to change the name of folders/users etc when posting, wasn't keeping up with my own 'lies'. The folder in question is MEDIA.

Comment: @roaima No, that's why I said "local user".

Comment: @aSystemOverload Samba is a privileged process, so it can do whatever pleases it. My point was that, if you want to support local users directly (not through some privileged daemon), then you can't control who the owner of the file is. Note that you *can* change the group owner on the file, though.

Answer (score 2):

Samba tends to force its own idea of permissions and ownerships on files so that it more closely mimics the (hierarchical) NTFS style of permissions.

If you extend your Samba definition to include the `force user` and `force group` directives you can ensure that all files created on the share (through Samba) will have the specified owner and group.

```
[MEDIA]
  read only = no
  locking = yes
  path = /mnt/local/int001/MEDIA
  guest ok = yes
  create mask = 0664
  directory mask = 0775
  force user = Bob
  force group = SharedFiles
```

You can't implement the same thing directly with local users, though, because it's not possible for a user to create a file owned by someone else. This is where `inotifywait` can help. Set it up at boot to monitor the directory hierarchy and change the ownership of any newly created file:

```
cd /mnt/local/int001/MEDIA || exit
inotifywait --monitor --recursive --event create --format '%w%f' . |
    while IFS= read -r file
    do
        if [[ -f "$file" || -d "$file" ]] && [[ ! -h "$file" ]]
        then
            chown Bob:SharedFiles "$file"
            chmod u+rw,go=u,o-w "$file"
        fi
    done
```

With this `inotifywait` solution you don't need the filesystem ACLs.

Personally, I'm not convinced you really need to change file ownership. The ACLs you specified (and the corresponding `force group` in Samba) will ensure that all users of the directory tree can access the files and directories within in. There is good reason for ordinary users being denied `chown`.